# How to capitalize selective words using mfirstuc and acro packages?

Tags: acronyms, capitalization, acro, mfirstuc

I'm using `mfirstuc` package for capitalize some words in an acronyms list. E.G.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
short=AE,
long=this is an example
}
\DeclareAcronym{AnE}{%
short=AnE,
long=this is another example,
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
We have \ac{AE} and \ac{AnE}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

How can I put in lower case the highlighted words?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
short=AE,
long=this\MakeLowercase{ is an} example
}
\DeclareAcronym{AnE}{%
short=AnE,
long=this \MakeLowercase {is another} example,
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
We have \ac{AE} and \ac{AnE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that only the *first* definition works properly -- you need to include an empty space inside `\MakerLowercase`, otherwise the first letter still comes out in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual of `mfirstuc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.pdf):

1. `\capitalisewords{a book of rhyme.}` produces:

   > A Book Of Rhyme.
2. `\capitalisewords{a book\space of rhyme.}` produces:

   > A Book of Rhyme.

In your case:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
  short=AE,
  long=this\space is\space an example
}
\DeclareAcronym{AnE}{%
  short=AnE,
  long=this\space is\space another example,
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
We have \ac{AE} and \ac{AnE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively `\MFUnocap{is}` etc if the word should always have the case change omitted mid-sentence (there are some more exclusions in `mfirstuc-english.sty`).